# Simple version of NEAT

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, ai, genetic-algorithm

I have wrote my own simple version of [NEAT](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/neat_overview.html) and want to improve the code for mainly performance
(training and runtime of a generation).
This simple version of NEAT aims to perform somewhere near as good as NEAT-python.
When I tested it against NEAT-python this was the result with similar configuration
(population 200 otherwise default settings, using my fitness function):

- NEAT-python: 130 generations (one test)
- simple version of NEAT: anywhere between 100 and 300 (many tests)

My simple version of NEAT performs on average 50% worse than NEAT-python.

An observation I have is that my algorithm likes to make jumps in fitness
and get stuck on that fitness for a while (mainly 0.5 and 0.75 for xor example).

Update - I have tried to train it to play paper scissors rock and each generation takes a couple of seconds when the network gets complicated(using @tdy's suggestions).

Update2 - I trained it for 1000 generations, the final network had over 40 hidden neurons! It does pretty good against the paper scissors rock bots and not bad against a human until they find its weakness.

### Code:

`activation_functions.py`

```
from numpy import exp

def sigmoid(x: float) -> float:
    return 1 / (1 + exp(-(x)))

activation_functions = {"sigmoid":sigmoid}
```

`FeedForwardNetwork.py`

```
import json
import random
import copy
import activation_functions


class FeedForwardNetwork:
    """
    FeedForwardNetwork

    - num_inputs: the number of inputs, int
    - num_outputs: the number of outputs, int
    - activation_function: the activation function of the network
    - neuron_data: the neuron data, list of lists|None

    The first num_outputs of neuron_data are output neurons

    Each item in neuron_data is data about the neuron

    - list[0]: the bias of the neuron, float
    - list[1]: the connections of the neuron, list of lists

    Each item in connections is data about the connection

    - list[0]: the neuron the connection is to
    - list[1]: the weight of the connection
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        num_inputs: int,
        num_outputs: int,
        activation_function: str,
        neuron_data: list,
    ):
        if num_outputs > len(neuron_data):
            raise RuntimeError("outputs < len(neuron_data)")
        self.num_inputs = num_inputs
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        self.neuron_data = neuron_data
        self.neuron_values = [None] * (len(neuron_data))
        self.inputs = [None] * num_inputs
        self.activation_function_str = activation_function
        self.activation_function = activation_functions.activation_functions[
            activation_function
        ]
        self.change_functions = (
            self.add_neuron,
            self.add_connection,
            self.change_weight,
            self.change_bias,
        )

        self.fitness = 0

    def activate(self, inputs):
        """
        Activates the FeedForwardNetwork with inputs.

        Args:
            inputs (list): A list of numerical values representing the input to the network.

        Returns:
            tuple: A tuple containing the output values of the FeedForwardNetwork.

        Raises:
            RuntimeError: If the number of inputs doesn't match the expected number of inputs.
        """
        if self.num_inputs != len(inputs):
            raise RuntimeError("self.num_inputs != len(inputs)")

        self.neuron_values = [None] * len(self.neuron_data)

        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            self.inputs[i] = inputs[i]

        return tuple([self.calculate_neuron(i) for i in range(self.num_outputs)])

    def calculate_neuron(self, neuron: int):
        """Calculates the output value of a specific neuron in the FeedForwardNetwork.

        Args:
            neuron (int): The index of the neuron whose value to calculate. A negative index accesses input neurons.

        Returns:
            float: The calculated value of the neuron.
        """
        if neuron < 0:
            return self.inputs[neuron]

        neuron_value = self.neuron_values[neuron]

        if neuron_value is not None:
            return neuron_value

        current_neuron_data = self.neuron_data[neuron]

        self.neuron_values[neuron] = 0  # avoid RecursionError

        value = self.activation_function(
            sum(
                [
                    self.calculate_neuron(conn) * weight
                    for conn, weight in current_neuron_data[1]
                ]
            )
            * current_neuron_data[0]
        )

        self.neuron_values[neuron] = value
        return value

    def mutate_neurons(self):
        """Makes a random change to the structure of a FeedForwardNetwork

        Returns:
            FeedForwardNetwork: the resulting network
        """
        mutation_type = random.randint(0, 1)
        output_neurons = range(self.num_outputs)
        in_neuron = random.choice(
            [
                neuron
                for neuron in range(-self.num_inputs, len(self.neuron_data))
                if neuron not in output_neurons
            ]
        )
        out_neuron = random.randrange(len(self.neuron_data))
        return self.mutate([(mutation_type, (in_neuron, out_neuron))])

    def mutate_weights(self, change_rate: float):
        """- change_rate: how much the weights and biases are changed, float

        Returns:
            FeedForwardNetwork: the resulting network
        """
        num_neurons = len(self.neuron_data)
        connections = [
            (neuron, connection)
            for neuron, data in enumerate(self.neuron_data)
            for connection in range(len(data[1]))
        ]
        num_connections = len(connections)

        changes = []
        for neuron, data in random.sample(
            list(enumerate(self.neuron_data)),
            k=round(num_neurons * random.uniform(0.5, 1.0)),
        ):
            changes.append(
                (3, (neuron, data[0] + (random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0) * change_rate)))
            )
        for neuron, connection in random.sample(
            connections, k=round(num_connections * random.uniform(0.5, 1.0))
        ):
            changes.append(
                (
                    2,
                    (
                        neuron,
                        connection,
                        self.neuron_data[neuron][1][connection][1]
                        + (random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0) * change_rate),
                    ),
                )
            )

        return self.mutate(changes)

    def mutate(self, changes: list):
        """- changes: a list of changes

        [(change; 0 to 3, (args)), ...]

        see the four change static methods for args

         - 0 = add_neuron
         - 1 = add_connection
         - 2 = change_weight
         - 3 = change_bias"""
        new_ffn = copy.deepcopy(self)
        for change_function, args in changes:
            self.change_functions[change_function](*args, new_ffn.neuron_data)
        return new_ffn

    def crossover(self, other):
        """Crosses over two FeedForwardNetworks weights and biases assuming they are the same structure

        Args:
            other: the other network to crossover with

        Returns:
            FeedForwardNetwork: the resulting network
        """
        new_ffn = copy.deepcopy(self)
        other_neuron_data = other.neuron_data
        for neuron, data in enumerate(other_neuron_data):
            new_ffn.neuron_data[neuron][0] = (
                data[0] + new_ffn.neuron_data[neuron][0]
            ) / 2.0
            for connection, c_data in enumerate(data[1]):
                new_ffn.neuron_data[neuron][1][connection][1] = (
                    c_data[1] + new_ffn.neuron_data[neuron][1][connection][1]
                ) / 2.0
        new_ffn
        return new_ffn

    @staticmethod
    def create_bare_minimum(
        num_inputs: int, num_outputs: int, activation_function="sigmoid"
    ):
        return FeedForwardNetwork(
            num_inputs,
            num_outputs,
            activation_function,
            [copy.deepcopy([0.0, []]) for i in range(num_outputs)],
        )

    @staticmethod
    def add_neuron(neuron_in: int, neuron_out: int, neuron_data: list) -> list:
        new_neuron_data = neuron_data
        new_neuron_data.append([0.0, [[neuron_in, 0.0]]])
        new_neuron_data[neuron_out][1].append([len(new_neuron_data) - 1, 0.0])

    @staticmethod
    def add_connection(neuron_in: int, neuron_out: int, neuron_data: list) -> list:
        new_neuron_data = neuron_data
        new_neuron_data[neuron_out][1].append([neuron_in, 0.0])

    @staticmethod
    def change_weight(
        neuron: int, connection: int, weight: float, neuron_data: list
    ) -> list:
        new_neuron_data = neuron_data
        new_neuron_data[neuron][1][connection][1] = weight

    @staticmethod
    def change_bias(neuron: int, bias: float, neuron_data: list) -> list:
        new_neuron_data = neuron_data
        new_neuron_data[neuron][0] = bias

    @staticmethod
    def network_to_json(feed_forward_network):
        return json.dumps(
            [
                feed_forward_network.num_inputs,
                feed_forward_network.num_outputs,
                feed_forward_network.activation_function_str,
                feed_forward_network.neuron_data,
            ]
        )

    @staticmethod
    def json_to_network(json_str: str):
        data = json.loads(json_str)
        return FeedForwardNetwork(*data)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        simplified_neuron_data = [
            [-(self.num_inputs - i) for i in range(self.num_inputs)],
            [
                i + self.num_outputs
                for i in range(len(self.neuron_data) - self.num_outputs)
            ],
            [i for i in range(self.num_outputs)],
        ]
        simplified_connections = [
            (connection[0], neuron)
            for neuron, data in enumerate(self.neuron_data)
            for connection in data[1]
        ]
        return str(simplified_neuron_data) + "\n" + str(simplified_connections) + "\n"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.neuron_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ffn = FeedForwardNetwork.create_bare_minimum(3, 2)
    print(ffn.activate([1, 1, 1]))

    new_ffn = ffn.mutate_neurons()
    print(new_ffn.activate([1, 1, 1]))

    new_new_ffn = new_ffn.mutate_weights(5.0)
    print(new_new_ffn.activate([1, 1, 1]))

    new_new_new_ffn = new_new_ffn.crossover(new_ffn)
    print(new_new_new_ffn.activate([1, 1, 1]))

    print(ffn)
    print(new_ffn)
    print(new_new_ffn)
    print(new_new_new_ffn)
```

`Species.py`

```
import math
from FeedForwardNetwork import FeedForwardNetwork


class Species:
    """Species

    - population: the size of the population, int
    - best_to_keep: how many networks to include in the fittest, int
    - change_rate: how much to change the networks weights when mutating, float
    - parent: the parent of the species, FeedForwardNetwork"""

    def __init__(
        self,
        population: int,
        best_to_keep: int,
        change_rate: float,
        parent: FeedForwardNetwork,
    ) -> None:
        self.best_to_keep = best_to_keep
        self.change_rate = change_rate

        self.parent = parent

        self.generations_alive = 0
        self.population_count = population
        self.population = []
        self.fittest = []
        self.repopulate([self.parent])

    def repopulate(self, parents=None):
        """Repopulates the species population with parents.
        If parents == None: parents = self.fittest
        """
        if parents == None:
            parents = self.fittest

        best = parents[0]
        self.population = parents + [best.crossover(parent) for parent in parents[1:]]

        mutations_needed = self.population_count - len(self.population)
        for index, parent in enumerate(parents):
            if index == len(parents) - 1:
                mutations_for_parent = mutations_needed
            else:
                mutations_for_parent = math.ceil(mutations_needed / 2)

            for i in range(mutations_for_parent):
                self.population.append(
                    parent.mutate_weights(self.change_rate)
                )

            mutations_needed -= mutations_for_parent

    def get_fittest(self):
        """sets self.fittest to the self.best_to_keep fittest of the species population"""
        self.fittest = sorted(self.population, key=lambda x: x.fitness, reverse=True)[
            : self.best_to_keep
        ]


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def xor(a, b):
        return bool(a) ^ bool(b)

    bare = FeedForwardNetwork.create_bare_minimum(2, 1)
    # best:
    # [[-34.71928105009088, [[1, -18.799558602148053], [2, 21.97129781931126]]], [-3.7697600919986067, [[-1, -5.2222081577237365], [-2, -8.675206506483445]]], [0.11407851623931986, [[-2, 10.820838527759477], [-1, 12.20712625251363]]]]
    # [1.2235905164272823e-24, 1.0, 1.0, 3.245832864766183e-26]
    # [0, 1, 1, 0]
    # 1.0
    # 500
    xor_parent = bare.mutate([(0, (-1, 0)), (0, (-2, 0)), (1, (-2, 1)), (1, (-1, 2))])
    xor_species = Species(20, 5, 5, xor_parent)

    try:
        gen = 0
        while True:
            gen += 1
            for ffn in xor_species.population:
                expected_output = [
                    int(xor(0, 0)),
                    int(xor(0, 1)),
                    int(xor(1, 0)),
                    int(xor(1, 1)),
                ]
                network_output = [
                    *ffn.activate([0, 0]),
                    *ffn.activate([0, 1]),
                    *ffn.activate([1, 0]),
                    *ffn.activate([1, 1]),
                ]
                difference = [
                    abs(expected - network)
                    for expected, network in zip(expected_output, network_output)
                ]
                ffn.fitness = 1 - (sum(difference) / len(difference))

            xor_species.get_fittest()
            xor_species.repopulate()

            best = xor_species.fittest[0]
            print(repr(best), sep="\n")
            print(
                [
                    *best.activate([0, 0]),
                    *best.activate([0, 1]),
                    *best.activate([1, 0]),
                    *best.activate([1, 1]),
                ]
            )
            print([int(xor(0, 0)), int(xor(0, 1)), int(xor(1, 0)), int(xor(1, 1))])
            print(repr(best.fitness), sep="\n")
            print(gen, "\n", sep="")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

`Population.py`

```
from FeedForwardNetwork import FeedForwardNetwork
from Species import Species


class Population:
    """Population

    - num_inputs: the number of inputs the network will have, int
    - num_outputs: the number of outputs the network will have, int
    - num_species: the number of species in the population, int
    - population_per_species: the size of the species populations, int
    - weight_change_rate: how much to change the networks weights when mutating, float
    - species_best_to_keep: how many networks to include in each species fittest, int
    - species_min_gens_alive: the minimum generations a species can run for, int
    - species_dont_remove: cutoff point for trying to remove bad species, 0 - 1, float
    - run_networks_func: function for running species and setting fitnesses, function
    - activation_function: the activation function of the network, default "sigmoid", str
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        num_inputs: int,
        num_outputs: int,
        num_species: int,
        population_per_species: int,
        weight_change_rate: float,
        species_best_to_keep: int,
        species_min_gens_alive: int,
        species_dont_remove: float,
        run_networks_func,
        activation_function="sigmoid",
    ) -> None:
        self.bare_ffn = FeedForwardNetwork.create_bare_minimum(num_inputs, num_outputs)

        self.species_best_to_keep = species_best_to_keep
        self.weight_change_rate = weight_change_rate
        self.population_per_species = population_per_species

        self.run_networks_func = run_networks_func
        self.species_min_gens_alive = species_min_gens_alive
        self.species_dont_remove = species_dont_remove
        self.population_of_species = []
        self.num_species = num_species
        self.populate_with_species(self.bare_ffn)

        self.generation = 0

    def populate_with_species(self, parent):
        """populates self.population_of_species with parent as the parent of the species"""
        self.population_of_species += [
            Species(
                self.population_per_species,
                self.species_best_to_keep,
                self.weight_change_rate,
                parent.mutate_neurons(),
            )
            for i in range(self.num_species - len(self.population_of_species))
        ]

    def run_generation(self):
        """runs a generation using the run_networks_func
        then does structure mutations, weight mutations and crossovers"""
        self.run_networks_func(
            [
                network
                for species in self.population_of_species
                for network in species.population
            ]
        )

        for species in self.population_of_species:
            species.get_fittest()
            species.repopulate()
            species.generations_alive += 1

        self.generation += 1

        self.remove_worst_species()
        best_network = self.sort_species_by_fitness(reverse=True)[0].fittest[0]
        self.populate_with_species(best_network)

    def remove_worst_species(self):
        """removes the worst species"""
        for index, species in enumerate(self.sort_species_by_fitness()):
            if (species.generations_alive > self.species_min_gens_alive) and index < (
                self.num_species * self.species_dont_remove
            ):
                self.population_of_species.remove(species)
                break

    def get_fitness_of_species(self, species):
        """gets the fitness of a certain species"""
        if not species.fittest:
            species.get_fittest()
        return species.fittest[0].fitness

    def sort_species_by_fitness(self, reverse=False):
        """sorts species by fitness"""
        return sorted(
            self.population_of_species, key=self.get_fitness_of_species, reverse=reverse
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def xor(a, b):
        return bool(a) ^ bool(b)

    xor_expected = [
        int(xor(0, 0)),
        int(xor(0, 1)),
        int(xor(1, 0)),
        int(xor(1, 1)),
    ]

    def run_network(network):
        return [
            *network.activate([0, 0]),
            *network.activate([0, 1]),
            *network.activate([1, 0]),
            *network.activate([1, 1]),
        ]

    def xor_run(networks):
        for ffn in networks:
            network_output = run_network(ffn)
            difference = [
                abs(expected - network)
                for expected, network in zip(xor_expected, network_output)
            ]
            ffn.fitness = 1 - (sum(difference) / len(difference))

    xor_population = Population(2, 1, 5, 20, 5.0, 4, 20, 0.75, xor_run)
    try:
        while True:
            xor_population.run_generation()

            best_species = xor_population.sort_species_by_fitness()[0]
            best_network = best_species.fittest[0]

            print(best_network)
            print(run_network(best_network))
            print(xor_expected)
            print(best_network.fitness)
            print(xor_population.generation, "\n", sep="")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(repr(best_network))
        with open("best", "w") as file:
            file.write(FeedForwardNetwork.network_to_json(best_network))

    with open("best", "r") as file:
        loaded_best = FeedForwardNetwork.json_to_network(file.read())
        print(loaded_best)
        print(run_network(loaded_best))
        print(xor_expected, "\n")
        print(repr(loaded_best))
```

`SimpleNeat.py`

```
import importlib
from FeedForwardNetwork import FeedForwardNetwork
from Population import Population


class SimpleNeatTrainer:
    """SimpleNeatTrainer
    
     - config_module: the imported config module, module
     - run_networks_func: the function that is called to run the networks, function"""
    def __init__(self, config_module, run_networks_func) -> None:
        self.run_networks_func = run_networks_func
        self.population = Population(
            config_module.num_inputs,
            config_module.num_outputs,
            config_module.num_species,
            config_module.population_per_species,
            config_module.weight_change_rate,
            config_module.species_best_to_keep,
            config_module.species_min_gens_alive,
            config_module.species_dont_remove,
            self.run_networks_func,
            config_module.activation_function,
        )
        self.best_networks = []
        self.generation = self.population.generation

    def run_generation(self):
        """runs generation and calls the run_networks_func"""
        self.population.run_generation()
        self.generation = self.population.generation

        best_species = self.population.sort_species_by_fitness()[0]
        self.best_networks.append(best_species.fittest[0])

    def save_network(self, save_file, network):
        """saves network to save_file"""
        with open(save_file, "w") as file:
            file.write(FeedForwardNetwork.network_to_json(network))

    def load_from_file(self, save_file):
        """loads a network from save_file and returns network"""
        with open(save_file, "r") as file:
            return FeedForwardNetwork.json_to_network(file.read())

    def get_best(self, first_to_fitness=None):
        """gets the best network
        
        if first_to_fitness != None the first network to reach first_to_fitness is returned"""
        if first_to_fitness == None:
            return self.best_networks[-1]
        for network in self.best_networks:
            if network.fitness > first_to_fitness:
                return network
        return self.best_networks[-1]
```

### Example code:

`example_config.py`

```
"""network
 - num_inputs: the number of inputs the network will have, int
 - num_outputs: the number of outputs the network will have, int
 - activation_function: the activation function of the network, default "sigmoid", str"""
num_inputs = 2
num_outputs = 1
activation_function = "sigmoid"

"""species
 - population_per_species: the size of the species populations, int
 - weight_change_rate: how much to change the networks weights when mutating, float"""
population_per_species = 20
weight_change_rate = 5.0

""" population
 - num_species: the number of species in the population, int
 - species_min_gens_alive: the minimum generations a species can run for, int
 - species_dont_remove: cutoff point for trying to remove bad species, 0 - 1, float
 - species_best_to_keep: how many networks to include in each species fittest, int"""
num_species = 5
species_min_gens_alive = 20
species_dont_remove = 0.75
species_best_to_keep = 4
```

`example.py`

```
from doctest import Example
from time import sleep
from SimpleNeat import SimpleNeatTrainer
import example_config


def xor(a, b):
    return bool(a) ^ bool(b)


xor_expected = [
    int(xor(0, 0)),
    int(xor(0, 1)),
    int(xor(1, 0)),
    int(xor(1, 1)),
]


def run_network(network):
    return [
        *network.activate([0, 0]),
        *network.activate([0, 1]),
        *network.activate([1, 0]),
        *network.activate([1, 1]),
    ]


def xor_run(networks):
    for network in networks:
        network_output = run_network(network)
        difference = [
            abs(expected - network)
            for expected, network in zip(xor_expected, network_output)
        ]
        network.fitness = 1 - (sum(difference) / len(difference))


def print_network_info(network):
    print(network)
    print(run_network(network))
    print(xor_expected)
    print(network.fitness)


xor_trainer = SimpleNeatTrainer(example_config, xor_run)
try:
    while True:
        xor_trainer.run_generation()

        best_network = xor_trainer.get_best()

        print_network_info(best_network)
        print(xor_trainer.generation, "\n", sep="")
        sleep(0)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(best_network)
    print([network.fitness for network in xor_trainer.best_networks])
    xor_trainer.save_network("best.txt", xor_trainer.get_best(0.999))

loaded_best = xor_trainer.load_from_file("best.txt")
xor_run([loaded_best])
print_network_info(loaded_best)
```

profile output of example.py (relevant bit only)

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.344    0.344 FeedForwardNetwork.py:1(<module>)
404184/88076    1.184    0.000    4.910    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:102(<listcomp>)
       55    0.001    0.000    0.026    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:113(mutate_neurons)
       55    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:122(<listcomp>)
    15171    0.443    0.000    9.023    0.001 FeedForwardNetwork.py:131(mutate_weights)
    15171    0.104    0.000    0.117    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:138(<listcomp>)
    15226    0.232    0.000    7.356    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:170(mutate)
     3261    0.069    0.000    1.588    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:186(crossover)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:208(create_bare_minimum)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:216(<listcomp>)
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:219(add_neuron)
       31    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:225(add_connection)
   128649    0.053    0.000    0.053    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:230(change_weight)
    52947    0.022    0.000    0.022    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:237(change_bias)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:242(network_to_json)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:253(json_to_network)
      219    0.007    0.000    0.009    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:258(__str__)
      219    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:260(<listcomp>)
      219    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:261(<listcomp>)
      219    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:265(<listcomp>)
      219    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:267(<listcomp>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:29(__init__)
    88076    0.533    0.000    6.650    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:56(activate)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:7(FeedForwardNetwork)
    88076    0.110    0.000    6.065    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:77(<listcomp>)
1080496/88076    1.744    0.000    5.955    0.000 FeedForwardNetwork.py:79(calculate_neuron)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 Population.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.024    0.024 Population.py:20(__init__)
      218    0.001    0.000    0.659    0.003 Population.py:48(populate_with_species)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Population.py:5(Population)
      218    0.001    0.000    0.658    0.003 Population.py:50(<listcomp>)
      218    0.013    0.000   17.812    0.082 Population.py:60(run_generation)
      218    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 Population.py:64(<listcomp>)
      217    0.001    0.000    0.004    0.000 Population.py:82(remove_worst_species)
     3205    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 Population.py:91(get_fitness_of_species)
      651    0.001    0.000    0.007    0.000 Population.py:97(sort_species_by_fitness)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.348    0.348 SimpleNeat.py:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.024    0.024 SimpleNeat.py:11(__init__)
      218    0.002    0.000   17.817    0.082 SimpleNeat.py:28(run_generation)
        1    0.001    0.001    0.002    0.002 SimpleNeat.py:36(save_network)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 SimpleNeat.py:41(load_from_file)
      218    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 SimpleNeat.py:46(get_best)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 SimpleNeat.py:6(SimpleNeatTrainer)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Species.py:1(<module>)
       55    0.000    0.000    0.632    0.011 Species.py:13(__init__)
     1142    0.153    0.000   10.785    0.009 Species.py:31(repopulate)
     1142    0.006    0.000    1.593    0.001 Species.py:39(<listcomp>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Species.py:5(Species)
     1137    0.005    0.000    0.033    0.000 Species.py:55(get_fittest)
    22740    0.010    0.000    0.010    0.000 Species.py:57(<lambda>)
```

edited - finished project

Comment: `mutate()` describes what indices {0,1,2,3} mean. Consider using a [@dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) instead, which would allow the use of names.

Comment: @J_H good idea, I just decided to turn self.change_functions into a dictionary with strings as keys.

Answer (score 5):

### Avoid unnecessary loops/comprehensions

- Replace this loop:

  ```
  # for i in range(len(inputs)):
  #     self.inputs[i] = inputs[i]
  ```

  with an O(1) assignment:

  ```
  self.inputs = inputs
  ```

  [image]
- Replace these comprehensions:

  ```
  # simplified_neuron_data = [
  #     [-(self.num_inputs - i) for i in range(self.num_inputs)],
  #     [
  #         i + self.num_outputs
  #         for i in range(len(self.neuron_data) - self.num_outputs)
  #     ],
  #     [i for i in range(self.num_outputs)],
  # ]
  ```

  with `list(range)` constructs:

  ```
  simplified_neuron_data = [
      list(range(-self.num_inputs, 0)),
      list(range(self.num_outputs, len(self.neuron_data))),
      list(range(self.num_outputs)),
  ]
  ```

  [image]

---

### Avoid cryptic numeric codes

The mutation codes (0, 1, 2, 3) just look like random numbers unless you find the legend (located in a separate function's docstring). That makes them hard to understand/maintain and thus bug-prone.

- Replace these numeric constants:

  ```
  # changes.append((3, ...))
  # changes.append((2, ...))
  # ...
  # new_ffn = ffn.mutate([(0, ...), (0, ...), (1, ...)])
  # new_new_ffn = new_ffn.mutate([(2, ...), (2, ...), (3, ...)])
  # ...
  # parent = bare.mutate([(0, ...), (0, ...), (1, ...)])
  # xor_parent = bare2.mutate([(0, ...), (0, ...), (1, ...), (1, ...)])
  ```

  with human-readable constants, e.g. as an [`Enum`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0435/):

  > [Enumerations] are useful for defining an immutable, related set of constant values that may or may not have a semantic meaning.

  ```
  from enum import Enum


  class Mutation(Enum):
      ADD_NEURON = 0
      ADD_CONNECTION = 1
      CHANGE_WEIGHT = 2
      CHANGE_BIAS = 3


  changes.append((Mutation.CHANGE_BIAS, ...))
  changes.append((Mutation.CHANGE_WEIGHT, ...))
  ...
  new_ffn = ffn.mutate([(Mutation.ADD_NEURON, ...), ...])
  new_new_ffn = new_ffn.mutate([(Mutation.CHANGE_WEIGHT, ...), ...])
  ...
  parent = bare.mutate([(Mutation.ADD_NEURON, ...), ...])
  xor_parent = bare2.mutate([(Mutation.ADD_NEURON, ...), ...])
  ```

Comment: I implemented these suggestions thanks, I was hoping someone would look at all of my code. (or did you and everything else was perfect??)

Comment: @coder I don't really know enough about NEAT to offer deeper insights, so that's why my answer is mainly about base python stuff. I suspect it'll be hard for others as well without prior/related expertise.

Comment: I mainly work with vectorization (numpy/pandas), but I see that your code requires recursion. You might consider extracting smaller parts for review (e.g. making a standalone version of the recursive `FeedForwardNetwork.calculate_neuron()` method). That would be easier for people to digest, and you might get someone who's good at recursion even if they don't know NEAT.

Comment: ok, I thought it would be best to post everything in one question as it's not much code. I have posted FeedForwardNetwork by itself (a while ago using an account I now can't access) and have had it optimized (not much, it was pretty good already).  I am mostly focused on base python stuff for performance stuff but I do want someone to check and see if the algorithm was alright.